# How can I find distance to clusters in k means clustering algorithm in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis

I am using k means algorithm in spark scala for training the model. I want to calculate the distance of each value in the clusters to each of the remaining clusters. Following is the code I implemented for training the model.

```
    val Array(trainingData, testData) = df2.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))
    val kmeans = new KMeans()
      .setK(12)
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setPredictionCol("prediction")
    val kmeansModel = kmeans.fit(trainingData)
    kmeansModel.clusterCenters.foreach(println)

    val predictDf = kmeansModel.transform(testData)
    predictDf.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compute the distances yourself (which is easy to do, so just so it!).

While the (poor) algorithm implemented by Spark does have these distances, they are currently not returned. So you would need to modify Spark to get them.

Better algorithms *avoid* computing all these distances to be faster. Which is why these algorithms are faster than Spark, which only has Lloyd's naive algorithm. But then these akgorithms also will not be able to return them. Some may have a bound on the distances, though. But you'll need a final O(n) pass to compute the exact distances, and you will usually need to do this yourself.

When "predicting" (note that clustering is usually *not* predictive, most will not provide a "predict" function, and nor is it common to do a train-test split therefore because it simply does not work), you may just as well implement (i.e., write the code yourself rather than using a library function) it yourself. Then you will have the distances to all cluster centers. This is smarter than recomputing the distance again afterwards (which is k+1 distance computations per point instead of k).

Last but not least, you may also be interested in Euclidean instead of squared Euclidean distances. These are *not* minimized by k-means (it only minimizes Bregman divergences, Euclidean distance is not), but usually the difference is not too large. Just so not assume the result is optimal.